# TSC Barcode Printer Programming

Tags: barcode, barcode-printing

I have two files .txt and .bat files. txt file has barcode printing program and batch file has command to send it to TSC printer.

txt file with below code:

```
SIZE 97.5 mm, 37 mm
DIRECTION 0,0
REFERENCE 0,0
OFFSET 0 mm
SET PEEL OFF
SET CUTTER OFF
SET PARTIAL_CUTTER OFF
SET TEAR ON
CLS
CODEPAGE 1252
TEXT 752,261,"0",180,6,8,""
TEXT 520,241,"0",180,16,20,""
TEXT 704,212,"0",180,9,11,""
BARCODE 752,159,"128M",70,0,180,2,4,"!104OR01234"
TEXT 708,83,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"OR01234"
TEXT 486,45,"0",180,8,9,""
PRINT 1,1
```

bat file with below code:

```
COPY <path_of_file> <TSC printer path>
del  <path_of_file>
EXIT
```

I have been using this to run batch file to print through TSC machine but it fails many times. When I restart TSC machine, then batch file works and prints the barcode. I have to each time switch-off / on the machine to make batch file printing method work.

Please advise on where am I missing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and read-back an awnser from the printer. Or in general set a RESPONSE to troubleshoot.
https://www.tscprinters.com/EN/DownloadFile/readpdf/support/4356/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf?file_type=0